# IE document viewport border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, border

In some versions of IE, there is a thin 2px border surrounding the document view port. I haven't noticed it for any other browsers yet. This poses a slight problem in calculating mouse positions for the page and client areas. Originally, I simply subtracted 2 from each of the calculations to account for the border.

But then, when I tested it in different versions of IE and different IE embedding programs, I noticed that in some cases, there is no border. So, simply doing a check for IE and subtracting 2 won't cut it.

Is there any way of getting the document view port border in IE?

**Example1:** finding mouse position inside object

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var isIE = (!window.addEventListener);
        window.onload = function(){
            var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
            if (isIE) foo.attachEvent('onmousemove',check_coords);
            else foo.addEventListener('mousemove',check_coords,false);
        }
        function check_coords(e){
            var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
            var objPos = getPos(foo);
            if (isIE) mObj = [window.event.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft-objPos[0], window.event.clientY+document.body.scrollTop-objPos[1]];
            else mObj = [e.pageX-objPos[0], e.pageY-objPos[1]];
            foo.innerHTML = mObj;
        }
        function getPos(obj){
            var pos = [0,0];
            while (obj.offsetParent){
                pos[0] += obj.offsetLeft;
                pos[1] += obj.offsetTop;
                obj = obj.offsetParent;
            }
            return pos;
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        body{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        #foo{
            border:3px solid black;
            position:absolute;
            left:30px;
            top:52px;
            width:300px;
            height:800px;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='foo'>Test test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

At coordinate [0,0], Internet Explorer (the one's that have the border) returns [2,2]

**Example2:** getting scrollbar width

```
alert(screen.width-document.body.clientWidth);
```

With a scrollbar width of 17px, Internet Explorer (versions that have the border) returns 21px, not accounting for the 2px borders on each side.

**UPDATE:**
So, I guess it actually *was* a default style that is applied to the body tag. Sorry guys! I had originally done a `document.body.style.borderWidth` to check if it was a css style. But I just realized a couple minutes ago, that I should have done `document.body.currentStyle['borderWidth']`. This returns `medium`. So, the correct way to get the viewport border *without* modifying the page (this ***ONLY*** applies to IE calculations), you will need to use `.currentStyle['borderWidth']`. The script appears to work in all other browsers, besides IE, without performing the border check (as far as I have checked). Furthermore, you only have to check for *borderWidth* in IE- padding or margin don't seem to matter. Also, when subtracting border-widths, make sure you're checking for `borderTopWidth` AND `borderLeftWidth`.

Anyways, I awarded the bounty to Samuel, since he was the first to mention it might be a default browser style.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "client area" - the document's view port?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I forget what its actually called.

Comment: @Azmisov but that border shouldn't be a problem: It's outside the document, and thus will not influence mouse position calculations. It's just that the `0,0` corner is moved a bit. Can you show an example where this is a problem?

Comment: That border should be there in any version of IE except for IE 9 in its standards mode (and obviously future IE versions in their respective standards rendering mode).

Comment: I added one more example for finding scrollbar width.

Comment: Can you define some cases? Which IE version did this happen on? .. that way the devs can quickly get to troubleshooting the question.

Comment: The border appears in every version of IE (unless the engine is embedded, such as the IETester Firefox plugin). It does not appear in IE9 during standards mode. By cases, are you referring to the examples above? The first is for a top-left mouse position of the yellow object. The second is a generic test that can be run for any site.

Comment: Does this page have a doctype?

Comment: The script is part of a library; so, depending on what website is using it, it could have a doctype, but doesn't have to. Can't you check to see what doctype is used though (http://tinyurl.com/2cynkwr)? I wouldn't know how cross-browser compatible that code is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it isn't the style of the body tag? I know that some browsers have a default style to the body tag.
To be safe I always put

```
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

in my stylesheet

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to fix it. I made a better example to demonstrate too.

Answer (score 0):

For better cross-browser consistency you should try to use some CSS reset like [Eric Meyer's CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or some modern front-end framework like [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com).

Comment: the OP have said: that border come from the browser client itself, is not a CSS issue!

Answer (score 0):

`function getPos(obj){`

`var pos = [0,0];`

`while (obj.offsetParent){`

`pos[0] += obj.offsetLeft-1;`

`pos[1] += obj.offsetTop-1;`

`obj = obj.offsetParent;`

`}`

`return pos;`

`}`

`</script>`

`<style>`

`body{ 
margin:0; 
padding:0;
border:none;
outline:none;
}`

`#foo{
border:3px solid #000;
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:50px;
margin:0;
padding:0;

outline:none;
width:300px; 
height:800px; 
background-color:yellow; 
}` 
`</style>`

`</head>`

`<body>`

`<div id='foo'>Test test</div>`

`</body>` 
`</html>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here's the solution I found: `document.body.clientLeft` is usually zero, but when IE's viewport has insets, it is 2. Thus you can substract this value from the event's coordinates.

```
var x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft;
var y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop - document.body.clientTop;
```